# ASP .NET MVC overriding when edit while multiple records are opened at once in different tabs-

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My custom MVC web application has an overriding problem. I have custom edit page and im edditing university teachers, so they all have a profile picture. This is my edit controller which loads the view.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (cf.CheckDBConnection() != true)
            {
                return View("~/Views/Error/NoDBConnection.cshtml");
            }

            if (checksession.CheckSessionState() != 1)
            {
                return View("~/Views/Error/NotAdmin.cshtml");
            }
            if (id == null)
            {
                return View("~/Views/Error/BadRequest.cshtml");
            }

            var disciplina = db.tblDisciplines.ToList();
            ViewBag.disciplina = disciplina;
            var specialies = db.tblSpecialities.ToList();
            ViewBag.specialty = specialies;

            var Ischecked = db.tblTeachersDisciplines.Where(p => p.TeacherID == id).Select(p => p.DisciplineID).ToArray();
            ViewBag.Checked = Ischecked;


            tblTeacher tblTeacher = db.tblTeachers.Find(id);
            var IscheckedSpec = db.tblTeachersSpecialities.Where(p => p.TeacherID == tblTeacher.ID).Select(p => p.SpecialityID).ToArray();
            ViewBag.CheckedSpec = IscheckedSpec;
            TempData["Photo"] = tblTeacher.ProfilePicture;
            if (tblTeacher == null)
            {
                return View("~/Views/Error/NotFound.cshtml");
            }

            var department = tblTeacher.TDepartment;
            ViewBag.department = department;

            return View(tblTeacher);
        }
```

This is the controller that runs after clicking "save"

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,FirstName,SecondName,Title,PersonalCabinet,Laboratory,TelNum,Email,VisitingHours,PersonalInterests,TDepartment,ProfilePicture")] tblTeacher tblTeacher, HttpPostedFileBase file, int[] discipline, int[] specialty, string department)
        {
            var disciplina = db.tblDisciplines.ToList();
            ViewBag.disciplina = disciplina;
            var specialies = db.tblSpecialities.ToList();
            ViewBag.specialty = specialies;

            var Ischecked = db.tblTeachersDisciplines.Where(p => p.TeacherID == tblTeacher.ID).Select(p => p.DisciplineID).ToArray();
            ViewBag.Checked = Ischecked;

            var IscheckedSpec = db.tblTeachersSpecialities.Where(p => p.TeacherID == tblTeacher.ID).Select(p => p.SpecialityID).ToArray();
            ViewBag.CheckedSpec = IscheckedSpec;

            tblTeacher.TDepartment = department;
            if (department == null ||  department == "")
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Изберете факултет");
                return View(tblTeacher);
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(tblTeacher);
            }
            if (discipline == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Моля, изберете дисциплини");
                return View(tblTeacher);
            }
            if (specialty == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Моля, изберете специалност");
                return View(tblTeacher);
            }            

            try
            {
                var _photo = TempData["Photo"];

                if (file != null)
                {
                    if (file.ContentLength > 0 && file.ContentLength < 1000000 && file.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
                    {
                        byte[] imageBytes = null;
                        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
                        imageBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)file.ContentLength);
                        _photo = imageBytes;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Профилната снимка е задължителна и трябва да отговаря на описаните условия!");
                        return View(tblTeacher);
                    }
                }

                tblTeacher.ProfilePicture = (byte[])_photo;
                db.Entry(tblTeacher).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.tblTeachersDisciplines.Where(p => p.TeacherID == tblTeacher.ID).ToList().ForEach(p => db.tblTeachersDisciplines.Remove(p));
                db.tblTeachersSpecialities.Where(p => p.TeacherID == tblTeacher.ID).ToList().ForEach(p => db.tblTeachersSpecialities.Remove(p));
                db.SaveChanges();

                for (int i = 0; i < discipline.Length; i++)
                {
                    using (RSEntities entities = new RSEntities())
                    {
                        tblTeachersDiscipline TD = new tblTeachersDiscipline
                        {
                            TeacherID = tblTeacher.ID,
                            DisciplineID = discipline[i]
                        };
                        entities.tblTeachersDisciplines.Add(TD);
                        entities.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < specialty.Length; i++)
                {
                    using (RSEntities entities = new RSEntities())
                    {
                        tblTeachersSpeciality TS = new tblTeachersSpeciality
                        {
                            TeacherID = tblTeacher.ID,
                            SpecialityID = specialty[i],
                        };
                        entities.tblTeachersSpecialities.Add(TS);
                        entities.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
                string _error = ex.ToString();
                _error = currentTime + " Exception: " + _error;
                SendMailOnErrorService mail = new SendMailOnErrorService();
                mail.Sendemail(_error);
                return View("~/Views/Error/DataBaseError.cshtml");
            }


        }
```

The problem seems to occur in this current scenario:
When i open many "Edit" tabs and i save all of them, they all change their profile picture with the one from the last tab opened.
I reckon the problem comes from`TempData["Photo"] = tblTeacher.ProfilePicture;`
as it probably takes the picture from the last tab opened and then when I save a tab it applies it to the current teacher profile. 
I use `TempData["Photo"] = tblTeacher.ProfilePicture;` because if I dont, when I edit-save a profile it erases the profilepicture from the database as it comes as null from the view and the controller on its behalf inserts null in the column from the DB.

One of the solutions may be not using TempData at all but what I want to know is why the problem occurs and how it can be solved while still using TempData

PS - I've done some testing and its 100% sure the problem is with `TempData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key string you are using for for `TempData` is "Photo". The value for returned from TempData for key "Photo" is whatever you last set it to in your HttpGet Edit method. If you have multiple Edit tabs open, the value for `TempData["Photo"]` will be whatever you last set it to for the last Edit tab open.

If you want to use `TempData` for each open Edit tab you would need a unique key for each Edit tab like so:

1. Edit tab 1: TempData["EditTab1_Photo"]
2. Edit tab 2: TempData["EditTab2_Photo"]

And so on.

And a unique TempData key for each Edit View request is not easy to do, you will have to generate a unique TempData key for each HTTP request and somehow know which key to use in the HttpPost Edit HTTP requests. Challenging and overly complex solution this is.

You do not have a ViewModel for your View and that is what you need, you should stop using `TempData` right away, see below for what `TempData` is used for.

The way to solve this problem is a standard ViewModel, an essential core tenant of how MVC data sharing is done between a View and a Controller. A Teacher ViewModel, which will have a `byte Photo {get;set;}` property among other properties that relate, mostly 1 to 1 in type and name as your `tblTeacher` entity,thus a unique instance of that Teacher ViewModel will be what is passed back and forth for each open Edit tab.

Currently you are sending the data Entity (tblTeacher) directly to the View which is not ever correct in a MVC design pattern. Your View should not depend on a persistence (database) Entity structure/representation, a structure which will change in the future and when that happens, it should not break your View, your View should depend on a ViewModel which translates your Entity into a structure specific to the View, the controller has the responsibility of translating/mapping the structure of the Entity and the ViewModel back and forth between HTTP requests.

A quote and article for you of what `TempData` is used for:

"TempData, on the other hand, is geared specifically for working with data on HTTP redirects, so remember to be cautious when using TempData."

http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3-applications/

Comment: Ok so first I will create a ViewModel. Then in the controller that returns the view I should find the DB record, asignt its values to the ViewModel, then pass the ViewModel to load the View with all the values displayed and when I click edit I should again find the DB record by model.ID and asign the rest of its properties with the values from what is passed through the ViewModel ?
Am I right or I didn't understand you at all

Comment: VisitorsViewModel visitor = new VisitorsViewModel();
            
            visitor.EGN = tblVisitor.EGN;
            visitor.FakNum = tblVisitor.FakNum;
            visitor.HasFirstLogin = tblVisitor.HasFirstLogin;
            visitor.ID = tblVisitor.ID;
            visitor.IsAdmin = tblVisitor.IsAdmin;
            visitor.Password = tblVisitor.Password;
            visitor.SDepartment = tblVisitor.SDepartment;
            visitor.SpecialityID = tblVisitor.SpecialityID;
            visitor.VoteForOwnSpeciality = tblVisitor.VoteForOwnSpeciality;

Comment: Is there a better way to asign the values from the View model to the Entity model than this?

Comment: @Georgi93 Automapper is the best

Comment: Just install via Nuget, then your ViewModel to Entity mappings and visa versa in your Global.asax.ApplicationStartup method http://automapper.org/